# How to return function results to dictionary values in Python, when passed the dictionary key as argument?

Tags: python, function, dictionary

The dictionary consists of financial instrument tickers from a list, with the values supposed to be a numeric value (in this case we can say the last close price for that ticker).

Example:

```
tickers = ("ticker1", "ticker2")

mydict = { tickers : tickervalue }
```

Now, I want a function to get passed the ticker value as an argument, use the argument to get the last close price from a source, and return it back to the dictionary as that ticker's value:

```
def tickervalue(*tickers):
    # code here
    return closeprice
```

In general, how do I go about structuring my code to achieve what I need? Is the above correct, as in:

```
mydict = { key : function_return }
```

or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dict comprehension:

```
tickers = ("ticker1", "ticker2")
mydict = {ticker: function(ticker) for ticker in tickers}
```

Another possibility is `map`, but I find it less readable:

```
mydict = dict(zip(tickers, map(function, tickers)))
```

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I needed :)